# Why can't I use GWT Button in a CellTable and how to combine cell buttons with cell text

Tags: gwt, datagrid, onclick, cell, col

I want to put some text and severals Buttons in a CellTable. I can display the text and buttons, but when I click on a button, nothing happens.

```
final SafeHtmlCell detailsCell = new SafeHtmlCell();
    Column<UIRow, SafeHtml> detailsColumn = new Column<UIRow, SafeHtml>(
            detailsCell) {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(UIRow object) {
            String details = "some informations xxx <br/>";

            Button addButton = new Button("Add value", new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                  Window.alert("hello");
                }
            });
            details += addButton;

    SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            sb.appendHtmlConstant(details);

            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
    detailsColumn.setCellStyleNames(CSS_DETAILS_TD);
    table.setColumnWidth(detailsColumn, "10%");
table.addColumn(detailsColumn, new SafeHtmlHeader(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("details")));
```

But, if I put a Button per Cell, it's working, onClick method is called:

```
        final ButtonCell btnCell = new ButtonCell() {
            @Override
            public void render(
                    final Context context,
                    final SafeHtml data,
                    final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\" style=\"height: 25px\" title=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-small\" tabindex=\"-1\">");
                if (data != null) {
                    sb.append(data);
                }
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("</button>");
            }
        };

        Column<UIRow, String> btnColumn = new Column<UIRow, String>(btnCell) {
            @Override
            public String getValue(UIRow object) {
                return "";
            }
        };
        btnColumn.setCellStyleNames("td-actions");
        table.addColumn(btnColumn, "");
        table.setColumnWidth(btnColumn, "5%");

        btnColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<UIRow, String>() {
            public void update(int index, UIRow object, String value) {

               ...

                service.submit(object, false, new AsyncCallback<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        Window.alert(result);
                    }

                });

            }
        });
    }
```

I want to display Html text and Buttons in one Col/Cell, is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell widgets (CellTable, DataGrid, etc) are not designed to embed regular GWT widgets like Button.

For buttons you can use [ButtonCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html)

Take a look at official example: 
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

**Update:**

As for the second part of the question regarding how to combine cells, there is a few options:

- Check out [CompositeCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html) where you can combine multiple cells (eg ButtonCell and TextCell).
- Another option is to use custom [CellTableBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTableBuilder.html) where you can customize all aspects of table rendering like colspans, column/row decorations, etc

Comment: I already use a ButtonCell if i want that my button works but my need is a text and severals button in a same cell/ column.

Comment: You have a few options: Check out CompositeCell where you can combine multiple cells (eg ButtonCell and TextCell). Another option is to use custom CellTableBuilder where you can customize all aspects of table rendering like colspans, column/row decorations, etc

Comment: Thx yurgis, I will take a look about that and take you inform.

Comment: It's working corectly with a CellComposite, thanks :-).

Comment: Ok, I improved my answer :)